# How can I crop only left and right sides of an image using ImageMagic

Tags: imagemagick

How can I remove a specific number of pixels from left and right sides of an image without knowing the width of the image:

I tried:

```
convert img.png -crop +200 result.png
```

But it only removes from the left side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-shave` like this to remove 200 pixels from left and right:

```
convert input.png -shave 200x0 result.png
```

Or like this for top and bottom:

```
convert input.png -shave 0x200 result.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative number to remove from the right side:

```
convert img.png -crop +200 +repage -crop -200 result.png
```